# How to get Chinese vaccines in Europe

Tags: visas, international-travel, europe, china, vaccinations

I'm a Norwegian citizen who wants to travel to China for work-related reasons. I have taken the Pfizer vaccine, but it is currently not recognized by China. The only way to get a work visa in China without a Chinese vaccine is by getting a PU letter, but this is only for essential workers. So I need a Chinese vaccine.

Is it possible to get a Chinese vaccine in Europe for people of foreign countries? I know Serbia was offering this, but this ended May 15th. I also know Hungary and some other countries have the vaccines, but I have not found anywhere them offering this to foreigners. The most common Chinese vaccines are Sinopharm, CoronaVac, and CanSinoBIO.

As I already have the Pfizer vaccine, I do not care about efficacy, only if the vaccine is approved by China.

Comment: Even if there were a country which allowed this, it’s far from certain they would allow someone already vaccinated to get another vaccine, as this is most certainly outside the allowed uses of the vaccine (i.e. scenarios that have been tested and validated by regulators).

Comment: Have you consulted with the Chinese Embassy in your country to see if your Pfizer vaccine would be accepted? [There are reports](https://www.reuters.com/world/china/chinas-us-embassy-has-begun-accepting-non-chinese-vaccine-records-2021-04-20/) that this sometimes works, but the policy appears to be inconsistent at the moment.

Comment: @mlc I already spoke to the Chinese embassy in Norway, however they don't accept it as of now.

Comment: @jcaron there’s no global vaccination database so as long as you don’t mention your previous Pfizer shot you should be good. Though the effects of having both are of course unknown.

Answer (score 1):

Look it up on https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/vaccines/.

E.g., currently, for  [Sinovac: CoronaVac](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/vaccines/7/)
, it is approved in 25 countries:

- [Albania](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/country/albania/)
- [Azerbaijan](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/country/azerbaijan/)
- [Brazil](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/country/brazil/)
- [Cambodia](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/country/cambodia/)
- [Chile](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/country/chile/)
- [China](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/country/china/)
- [Colombia](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/country/colombia/)
- [Dominican Republic](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/country/dominican-republic/)
- [Ecuador](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/country/ecuador/)
- [Egypt](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/country/egypt/)
- [El Salvador](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/country/el-salvador/)
- [Hong Kong](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/country/hong-kong/)
- [Indonesia](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/country/indonesia/)
- [Lao People's Democratic Republic](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/country/lao-peoples-democratic-republic/)
- [Malaysia](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/country/malaysia/)
- [Mexico](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/country/mexico/)
- [Pakistan](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/country/pakistan/)
- [Panama](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/country/panama/)
- [Philippines](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/country/philippines/)
- [Thailand](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/country/thailand/)
- [Tunisia](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/country/tunisia/)
- [Turkey](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/country/turkey/)
- [Ukraine](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/country/ukraine/)
- [Uruguay](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/country/uruguay/)
- [Zimbabwe](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/country/zimbabwe/)

E.g., Turkey is partly in Europe.

Another example:  [Sinopharm (Beijing): BBIBP-CorV](https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/vaccines/5/) is approved to be used in some European countries, e.g. Belarus and Hungary.

Comment: Just because Chinese vaccines are approved in Turkey doesn't answer the OP's question asking how to actually obtain them there.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica no but it tells you where to look for it.